# Android Menu Items not visible using `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` theme

Tags: android, themes, android-menu, android-navigation

Building a simple app with an overflow menu. The overflow menu shows up fine, however the actual MenutItems are not visible. Theme is current set to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`.

[image: Screenshot]

But when I switch the theme to `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar`, it works just fine:

[image: Screeneshot 2]

Here is the menu.xml:

```xml
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- TODO Step 9.1 - Add an item for the settings fragment -->

    <item android:id="@+id/settings_dest"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
          android:menuCategory="secondary"
          android:title="@string/settings"
          android:visible="true"
          android:enabled="true"
          app:showAsAction="never|withText"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/settings_second"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
          android:menuCategory="secondary"
          android:title="Second"
          android:visible="true" android:enabled="true" android:checkable="true"/>

    <!-- TODO END STEP 9.1 -->
</menu>
```

And the style.xml:

```xml
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name = "actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorBlack</item>
    </style>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: that box is visible.. text color is white

Comment: Can you post the definition of `colorBlack` from color.xml?

Comment: Try to set black text color in theme `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#0000</item>   <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#0000</item>`

Comment: I use `widget.Toolbar` and had the same issue. Adding `app:popupTheme="@style/Platform.MaterialComponents.Light"` to `<Toolbar>` fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try addung your parent theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
</style>
```